# How to display images in grid from a loop in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to display images in row and columns...row should be of 4...the number of images will be random..

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import BytesIO

root = tk.Tk()

#number of urls will be random
URL_list = ["urls","urls","urls"]


for url in URL_list:

    u = urlopen(url)
    raw_data = u.read()
    u.close()

    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

    label = tk.Label(image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: my output]

Comment: You are using which version of python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grid geometry manager puts the widgets in a 2-dimensional table. The master widget is split into a number of rows and columns, and each “cell” in the resulting table can hold a widget. You can read more about it [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

To limit number of rows used, you can simply keep track of where you place your images.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import BytesIO

root = tk.Tk()

#number of urls will be random
URL_list = ["urls","urls","urls"]

MAX_ROWS = 4
current_row = 0
current_column = 0

for url in URL_list:

    u = urlopen(url)
    raw_data = u.read()
    u.close()

    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

    label = tk.Label(image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.grid(row = current_row, column = current_column)
    current_row += 1
    if (current_row >= 4):
        current_column += 1
        current_row = 0

root.mainloop()
```

This will place your images in following order:

```
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 ...
4 8
```

Comment: can you help me putting a scrollbar in this app